# Connect to WiFi from QML

Tags: qml, wifi

Is it possible to connect to WiFi from QML (without writing some C++ code)?

According to [this article](http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtfordevicecreation-wifi-wifi-qml-example.html) it is possible. And this article starts right away with `import B2Qt.Wifi 1.0`, implying that such module is available, but I get an error `module "B2Qt.Wifi" is not installed`.

I have a commercial Qt 5.7 and I installed all the components, so it should be there. However, there is no module with such name in the entire installation directory.

I tried to do it on Windows and Linux with the same result.

Maybe I need to download this module from somewhere else? That would be weird though.

Comment: According to [this](http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/index.html) the article that you pointed out, relates to Qt for embedded Linux only. Anyway what a problem to use C++ code? For example, the B2Qt.Wifi plugin from the article written in C++, not in QML :)

Comment: Of course, it's not a problem to do it with C++. It's just since this article exists, it exists for some reason, right, and it describes how to do it with QML, so it would be nice if it'd be actually possible :) As for embedded Linux only - it's not, it should work everywhere and anyway it should be compiled on Desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B2Qt means 'Boot to Qt'. It's for the devices where you prepare an image and then flash it onto the device.

So, it uses a specific network manager that is built into that image. And there is a `B2Qt.Wifi` module to configure that specific network manager.

I think it won't work with the network managers on desktop Linux, Mac or Windows.

Comment: Well, no. In any way, first you compile the app on desktop and then you deploy it to device. So it should be compiled on desktop OS. BTW, it should work on desktop OS as well :) And also embedded Linux is not that different from desktop Linux.

Comment: Get the sources if possible (I don't know if they're a part of the main repository), find out how it calls to the network manager. Even if you take Linux server and desktop, there differences: servers usually use `/etc/network/interfaces` config while desktops use a separate network manager. So, at least, it needs two backends. (I bet backends for other OS don't exist)

Comment: That's the thing, these sources are nowhere to find even though I have a commercial version and everything should be included. That's why I asked the question, because I'm really confused with this article.

Comment: I think that it's in the 'Building Your Own Embedded Linux Image' (http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-custom-embedded-linux-image.html). All B2Qt topics: http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/index.html

Comment: No, that's about building Yocto Linux image, it's not within the IDE, and the article I'm struggling with is about creating an app in IDE (Qt Creator).

Comment: @retif, the 'building Yocto Linux image' is where the sources are.

Comment: Ok, you were right after all. Not entirely, but that was a right direction. So, I was trying all this with Qt 5.7 for Raspberry Pi toolchain, and it simply does not contain `B2Qt.Wifi` module. So I installed Qt 5.6 toolchain for Raspberry Pi and here it is. In other words, it depends in toolchain. Weird they don't have it for 5.7 though.